# Why can't I enable any API services in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform

Cannot click "Enable" on any Google API service in the Google Cloud console

Keeps telling me to refresh the page as something went wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: There was outage in services. For further details read https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138349248. It is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an outage[1], you might need to wait for the issue to be resolved.

[1]https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/compute/19004#19004001